# difference between variational inference and gibbs sampler

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian, sampling, variational-analysis

I am learning about variational inference and Gibbs simpler.
I am in the process of deriving variational inference on my own. In this process, I need to make a comparison with Gibbs sampler.
I am reading the book "**Machine learning a probabilistic perspective" by Kevin Murphy** and I found this sentence that I need help with

> "Since we are replacing the neighboring values by their mean value,
> the method is known as mean field. This is very similar to Gibbs
> sampling (Section 24.2), except instead of sending sampled values
> between neighboring nodes, we send mean values between nodes."

Someone please explain how Gibbs sampling sends sampled values between neighbors and VI sends mean values between nodes.
I am looking for an in-depth explanation that shows what is what and how it is meant by this comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Since we are replacing the neighboring values by their mean value,
> the method is known as mean field. This is very similar to Gibbs
> sampling (Section 24.2), except instead of sending sampled values
> between neighboring nodes, we send mean values between nodes."

Let's call $q(\textbf x)$ the distribution that we're trying to sample from where $\textbf x$ (usually represented by $\theta$) is the parameter vector $(x_1,\dots,x_d)$.

Gibbs sampling works by drawing values from the conditional distribution of $x_i$ using the value passed on from the previous iterations, hence 'sending sampled values across neighboring nodes.' That is, Gibbs sampling works by:
Initialize $\textbf x^{(0)}=(x_1^{(0)}, \dots, x_d^{(0)})$
On each iteration, generate each coordinate through using the most recent value:
\begin{align}x_1^{(j)}&\sim q_1(x_1|x_2^{(j-1)},\dots,x_d^{(j-1)})\\
x_2^{(j)}&\sim q_2(x_2|x_1^{(j)}, x_3^{(j-1)},\dots,x_d^{(j-1)})\\
&\vdots\\
x_d^{(j)}&\sim q_d(x_d|x_1^{(j)},\dots,x_{d-1}^{(j)})\end{align}

Mean field method first assumes that the posterior distribution factorizes into some subset of the parameters:

$$q(\textbf x) = \prod _{i=1}^D q_i(\textbf x_i)$$ where $D<d$.

The update rule for each iteration is:

$$\log q_j(\textbf x_j) = \mathbb E_{-q_j}[\log \tilde p(\textbf x)]+\text{const}$$

where for example if there are three parameters $\mathbb E_{-q_2}[f(\textbf x)] = \sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_3}q(x_1)q(x_3)f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$

This can be written iteratively for one iteration as:

\begin{align}
\log q_1(\textbf x_1) &= \mathbb E_{-q_1}[\log \tilde p(\textbf x)]+\text{const}\\
\log q_2(\textbf x_2) &= \mathbb E_{-q_2}[\log \tilde p(\textbf x)]+\text{const}\\
\vdots\\
\log q_D(\textbf x_D) &= \mathbb E_{-q_D}[\log \tilde p(\textbf x)]+\text{const}
\end{align}

Since we are using the Expected Value (mean) of say $q_1$ in the second step for $q_2$'s expected value this is like passing the mean from step to step.

Answer (score 1):

For every node $x_n$ in a graphical model, we can use Gibb's sampling to sample from them in an iterative fashion:
$$
x^s_{n}\sim P(x_n|x_{mb}^{s-1})
$$
where $x_{mb}$ is the Markov blanket of $x_n$.  For every neighboring node $x_{i}^{s-1}$ of $x_n^s$, we update them in the same fashion (using $x_n^s$):
$$
x_i^s\sim P(x_i|x_n^s, x_{mb}^{s-1})
$$
We continue this until all nodes are updated in iteration $s$. This is what the book meant by sending sampled values between neighboring nodes; We update each node by sampling from the neighboring node.

---

Mean field VI on the other hand finds the distribution $q$ such that it's KL divergence between the target distribution is minimized. The assumption of mean field is that $$
q_\psi(x_1\cdots x_n)=q(x_1)\cdots q(x_n)
$$
Derivations shows that we can get $q(x_i)$ by updating them iteratively for $j=1:n$ and $s = 1:T$

$$
g_s(z_j)=E_{z_{mb_j}}[\log P(z_j,z_{mb_j})]\\
q_s(z_j)\propto \exp(g_s(x_j))
$$
As shown, we get the mean of the complete log joint of the nodes with respect to the Markov blanket of that node to update the Variational parameters for that node.

---

Gibb's sampling is a form of Metropolis Hastings Algorithm (an MCMC method) with 100% acceptance rate while Mean Field is a VI method that optimizes surrogate distributions instead of directly sampling from the target distribution.

Further details in this [book](https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book2.html)

Comment: thank you for your help and for this great reference.